# Bad path trying to open file in Android

Tags: android, file, path

I'm trying to open a file with this:

```
document = builder.parse(new File("Data.xml"));
```

and I'm getting this message:

> /Data.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

and the file is in the root directory of the android project.

Comment: Where is Data.xml? Filepath should be complete path to the file.

Comment: In the root of the proyect. But the complete path is relative to the path where is installed on the android device? i'm confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to open a file located in `/` (in linux this is the root directory of your file system). Instead you should be trying to create a file either on the SDCard or within the local storage directory for your application.

See this for more clarification: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Move `Data.xml` into the `assets` folder of your project. Then to get a file reference, call `getResources().getAssets().openFd( "Data.xml" )`

Comment: the problem is, i need to download the xml file from internet, i could put it there?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try using a file input stream constructor for the builder instead, and use openFileInput( String fileName ) to get that, which does only use your app's data directory.

[Using persistent storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

[openFileInput()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: i'd follow the recommendation to parse the xml as a X3C Document. Take a look: Http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html