# what is on pollduring alarm illegalstateexception in android

Tags: android, exception

My application was OK until I noticed this: sometimes the application crashes. When it happens, I check the logcat.

```
01-08 06:12:07.123: E/ThrottleService(755): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The problem is that I can't debug it. And there is no hint for the error. It happened in my mobile device too. What can be the reason to such an app crash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620641/android-error-open-failed-enoent , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235888/bad-path-trying-to-open-file-in-android. Check that. It might help

Comment: @MenukaDevinda `/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all`, does your process has read permissions on system folder proc ? Are you trying to read network info ?

Comment: I don't use any assets out side the application. I use fonts in my application assets folder

Comment: I am having the same problem. My app tries to read network info. What is the cause of this error message?